# how to use variable "last row number" to set the range in another column

Tags: excel, vba

The data file has value 1 to 10 from A1 to A10.

```
      A    B
1     1    1
2     2    1
3     3    1
4     4    1
5     5    2
6     6    2
7     7    2
8     8    2
9     9    2
10    10   3
```

I need insert a column (eg column B) to my data file. In Cell B1 there is a formula (eg: (=INT(A1/5)+1)). I usually double click the right-bottom corner of cell B1, this auto-filling the rest of cells in column B to the row with data in column A (as shown in table above)

By using record Macro, it gave me codes below:

```
Range("B1").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B10")
Range("B1:B10").Select
```

The problem is the data files have different last row number with data(it might be row 8 or row 14). So the macro created as above won't fit the other data files.

I know using macro below, it finds last row with data.

```
lastRow = Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row
```

How can I replace B10 in the range "B1:B10" with the variable?
I would like to have a common macro. Could someone help on this? Appreciated!!

Comment: Range("B1:B" & lastrow).Select

Answer (score 2):

Also, added to my comment, recording is a great tool, but can add some unnecessary "Select" statements. Your lines (with lastrow) can be just:

```
Range("B1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B" & lastrow)
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need Autofill for this. You can assign the formula in one go to the entire range

```
Range("B1:B" & Lrow).Formula = "=INT(A1/5)+1"
```

Where `LRow` is the LastRow.

> lastRow = Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row

Please do not hard code values like `99999` to find the last row. See [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) on how to find the last row.